# Using Freemember, I get this message "This website only accept registrations through the main registration form"

Tags: ee2, freemember

I'm using Freemember for my registration form. When I click submit, I get this message: "This website only accept registrations through the main registration form". Any ideas on how to resolve this?

I found this same issue here https://getsatisfaction.com/addonbakery/topics/_this_website_only_accept_registrations_through_the_main_registration_form but the solution provided is for the Simple Registration add-on.

The solution is a config variable, however I cannot find anything in the Freemember documentation that says I need to set a config.

I'm using EE 2.8.1, MSM, and Freemember 2.3.1.

Comment: I've never seen or heard of that error before. I'm almost certain it's not caused by FreeMember or EE. Do you happen to have Simple Registration (or another registration plugin) installed as well?

Comment: I do have Simple Registration installed. So perhaps it was a conflict between the two? I will uninstall SR to see if this alleviates the problem.

Comment: Sounds good. If that does help, don't forget to come back and post the solution as an 'answer' below so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: Following the fix for Simple Registrations should work for you (if you are using it for something) as would uninstalling Simple Registration if you don't need it. Had the same issue a while back.